# How to open telegram from cmd windows

Tags: python

```
elif cmd == 'open_Telegram':
    text = "Запускаю телеграм"
    tts.va_speak(text)
    os.startfile('C:\Users\likop\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe')
```

when i run this code i give this problem `[WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\likop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp9t13ry7t'`

Comment: "The process cannot access the file because the file is in use by another process" are you already running telegram?

Comment: No i close this + it must run wen i talk "open_telegram"